# Are there other protocols for enforcing AAA besides RADIUS?

Tags: ieee-802.11, access-point, radius

I know this is not the ideal question format but I need to lean upon the expertise in this community.

I am looking for a simpler method of implementing AAA (Authentication, Authorization and Accounting) for approximately 20 users on an IEEE 802.11 access point.  RADIUS works well but limiting the amount and duration of sessions is really messy and tedious to set up for a small set of users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there other protocols for enforcing AAA besides RADIUS?
>
> ...
>
> I am looking for a simpler method of implementing AAA (Authentication, Authorization and Accounting) for approximately 20 users on an IEEE 802.11 access point.

As this indicates you are talking about WPA2-Enterprise, the short answer is no. 802.11 uses 802.1X authentication for this purpose which makes use of EAP authentication methods and a RADIUS server. There is no other AAA solution that will work.

> RADIUS works well but limiting the amount and duration of sessions is really messy and tedious to set up for a small set of users.

This seems to be the actual heart of your question but you don't actually define the problems you are having or why you may need to limit amount/duration of user sessions. Product recommendations are off topic here, but there are many different implementations of RADIUS (as well as tools to manage RADIUS servers) and they all have their strengths/weaknesses.

Comment: To be clear, I am not asking for product recommendations.

Comment: @Notamachine, understood. Sometimes when someone mentions different implementations the follow up is "which one works best for..." types of comments. Just wanted to avoid that possibility. I would suggest if the RADIUS solution you are using isn't quite right that you could ask on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) where recommendations are allowed. If you do so, posting a link to that question in our chat may get you some more views by people who might have some suggestions.

Comment: Adding a link the my posting on Software Recommendations - https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/72179/radius-server-and-interface-configuration-tools